# Pyspark gives these at every time i start

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

every time i run pyspark i got these errors and if i ignored them when i just write sc it gives NameError: name 'sc' is not defined any help ??

```
pyspark
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/08/07 13:57:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop     library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 45, in <module>
spark = SparkSession.builder\
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 186, in _do_init
self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 259, in _start_update_server
server = AccumulatorServer(("localhost", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Please provide which version of Spark are you using, which distribution exactly it is? Thank you

Comment: thank you for giving attention i solved my problem after 1 week of searching i found that the solution is by adding localhost to /etc/hosts file !!!! i just did it and every thing got well

Answer (score 0):

After 1 week of search i just found the solution just by add localhost to file /etc/hosts and then every thing went well